# Can I still trade if I am F2P?

Tags: team-fortress-2

On TF2 I have just gotten some weapons I am not fond of, or just cannot use. Can I still trade even though I am considered Free to Play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as a F2P player, you can trade, but you are limited in what you can.

Drops that you recieve in-game cannot be traded, except for tools (such as crates, keys and name tags). These will have the `non-tradeable` tag in your inventory.

However, items that other players gift you *can* be traded. Therefore, if a Premium friend gifts you some items, you can then trade them for something else with someone else.

---

Should you choose to upgrade, all non-achievement items obtained through drops that are previously non-tradable will be available for trading.
(Achievement items, as always will stay untradable regardless of the account type)

Comment: Just to point out - All achievement items (regardless if you're a paid or free player) **are non-tradable**.

Comment: @AndrewEckert If this answer helped please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick below the votes. Thankyou!